# How can I get all child nodes of general tree in Python

Tags: python, tree, child-nodes

My tree has the following structure:
tree={'0':('1','2','3'), '1':('4'), '2':('5','6'), '3':(), '4':('7','8'), '8':('9','10','11')}

How can I wrote Python code to retrieve all given child nodes of a particular node? 
For example, if I give it node 4, the code should retrieve 7,8,9,10,11. 
For node 2, it should retrieve 5, 6 and so on.

I just started learning the basics of Python but I have no idea how to implement this for non-binary trees..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can use a queue.

Once you've gotten the user's requested value, push it into the queue. Then, while the queue isn't empty, pop a value, print it, check the dict, and if the current value is a key in the dict, add each of *those* values to the queue to check them in the next pass.

```py
import queue

tree={'0':('1','2','3'), '1':('4'), '2':('5','6'), '3':(), '4':('7','8'), '8':('9','10','11')}

num = input("what you want ")

q = queue.Queue()

q.put(num)

while not q.empty():
  n = q.get()
  for s in n:
    print(s)
    if s in tree:
      q.put(tree[s])
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/DualDarlingBucket)

Note that if you have a tree `tree={'0':('1'), '1':('0')}`, or any other circular reference, this code will run forever. Be careful!

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly! Is there anyway this could also be implemented by using recursion?

Comment: Certainly! Instead of using a queue, use a list to hold the current keys. Create a function that loops through each key. For each key, get all of the values, put them in a list, and then call the function with that list. Once the list is done, or if it's empty, print the current value and return.